# Alchemy getNFTsForCollection giving 'Subdomain not recognized.' as response

Tags: web3js, alchemy

I'm using the getNFTsForCollection endpoint and running into an issue as I age through.  I run one initial API call, then each subsequent call has the startToken attribute included for paging.  I get to exactly 50 and then get 'Subdomain not recognized.' as the error.  Then I can't move on because I don't have a new startToken.

Is this a limitation of the free version of the API?  Is landing right on 50 just a coincidence, or is it significant?

Kind of unrelated, but is there a different way to control navigation along the API other than just using the nextToken as startToken us the url?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The issue was something to do with my paging logic :( I thought it was working, but I accidentally got the code to update the startToken every time, thus getting stuck on one and finally getting throttled by Alchemy after 50 of the same request in a row :)

Thanks,

Mark